# Simplifying 2D Navier stokes equation over the top and bottom part of an airfoil - assumptions incompressible, steady, very high viscosity

Tags: fluid-dynamics, differential-equations, viscosity, navier-stokes

I am trying to simplify the Navier-Stokes equations with my assumptions, to be able to solve them numerically:

I'm trying to model an airfoil flying through a very viscous fluid at relatively low speeds

Assumptions are:
Change in hydrostatic pressure is approximately = 0
2D => no z and w terms
steady => ∂u/∂t = 0
incompressible => ρ can be taken outside the derivative term
very high viscosity => convective terms are insignificant compared to viscous terms

Thus my equations become:
x momentum equation: ∂P/∂x= ν(∂^2u/∂x^2 + ∂^2u/∂y^2)
y momentum equation: ∂P/∂y= ν(∂^2v/∂x^2 + ∂^2v/∂y^2)
continuity: ∂u/∂x + ∂v/∂y = 0

Is everything I have done so far correct?

If so then I think the fact that my flow curves along the airfoil should somehow be incorporated into these equations but I don't know how.

I'm also a bit confused about how would it be possible to incorporate the airfoil into my boundary conditions,

Finally, how would the equations and boundary conditions change between the top and bottom parts of the airfoil- Specifically talking about an airfoil like this where the mean camber line is above the chord line:
http://airfoiltools.com/airfoil/details?airfoil=naca2412-il

Many thanks

Comment: I think you are also going to want to go to a steam function representation, with the biharmonic of the stream function equal to zero.

Comment: @ChetMiller could you please link the relevant sources (books/journals) for me and for future people who might stumble upon this? Also, do you mean stream functions?

Comment: Transport Phenomena, Bird, Stewart, and Lightfoot.